# Disk device (partially) not detected

Tags: boot, grub2, disk

It all started when my laptop begun to randomly restart, probably due to some battery issues.

Now, when booting from grub, it fails and says:

```
ALERT! UUID=(uuid value) does not exist. Dropping to a shell
```

The uuid is the root value in linux command in grub.

Other symptoms are as follows:

- When booting from LiveCd, there is no disk device under /dev/
- The disk and my Ubuntu partition can be accessed from grub shell (the
  one    which is entered by editing a grub entry), so clearly the disk
  still    works
- Windows on another partition works fine

systemctl --all:
https://pastebin.com/raw/NA6vK9hv

dmesg:
https://pastebin.com/raw/ExW5bFLa

This issue should be easily repairable, if only the disk device was there when booting from LiveCD. Any hints what can be done in this case?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the output to `smartctl --all /dev/sda` (or `b` instead of `a` depending on the disk you're having problems with...  After that, leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: @Fabby thanks for showing your interest. I just edited it. As I said, there is no disk device under /dev/. It used to be /dev/nvmxxxx or something like that

Comment: Not `systemctl`: `smartctl --scan` if it's an NVME (**Warning:** it's probably broken and needs replacing)

Comment: Did you update UEFI and it changed to defaults? You show this: [    6.703789] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Found 1 remapped NVMe devices.
[    6.703790] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI mode to use them.

Comment: @oldfred Such a great find. Indeed it was the culprit. Apparently resetting laptop reset the UEFI default settings. If you make it an answer I will grant you the bounty. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like either a reset of UEFI to defaults or an update to UEFI reset it to defaults. And then RAID is the default. With Ubuntu you need to change RAID to AHCI. And if dual booting with Windows add AHCI driver before changing.

You show this:

```
[ 6.703789] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Found 1 remapped NVMe devices. 
[ 6.703790] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI mode to use them.
```

Note that Windows updates, UEFI update and now with some systems even an UEFI update from Ubuntu may reset some UEFI settings. I like to keep a list and if I notice change or update,  or have issues, I double check that settings are what I expect.

UEFI systems that now support update from Linux.

https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist

https://fwupd.org/vendorlist

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying to first force mount your sda1 device from your liveCD and bind sys, proc and dev 

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys 
sudo chroot /mnt`

and attempt to update-grub afterwards.

`update-initramfs -u
update-grub
reboot`

If that doesn't work then since you can access grub and select other partitions, could you provide the grub configuration that shows up when you select the broken OS and press 'e' for advanced options.