# SSD and HDD not detected on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, m2

I am very new to Linux. I have been flirting with the idea of learning how to run it as the core OS for some time, but always gave up due to learning curve too steep.
I am determined now to make it work, so trying to get Ubuntu 22.04 work on my brand new PC (MSI Z690 MB).
I have an issue now: I have 2 M2 SSD drives. Only one is detected and Ubuntu is seating on this (slot 1). I have another M2 SSD drive in slot 2 and 2 sata drives that are not seen by the OS.
Not sure what to do about this.
Bios sees the drives fine.
Hope to be able to resolve this.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest version and updated the SSD's to latest firmware. Even new system often need updates. Are drives seen correctly in UEFI? On WiFi issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392532/wifi-and-bluetooth-on-msi-pro-z690-a-wifi-motherboard Open Benchmark: https://openbenchmarking.org/s/MSI%20PRO%20Z690-A%20DDR4(MS-7D25)%20v1.0%20(1.00%20BIOS) & https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-12600k-12900k&num=1 MSI PRO Z690-A DDR4 test: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ddr4-ddr5-alderlake&num=1

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Comment: Remember all the settings changes required in your system. A UEFI/BIOS update often resets some or all of them back to defaults. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116908/disk-device-partially-not-detected/1119549#1119549